# Generic DB Table

Tags: database, entity-attribute-value

Is there any name for the following DB table design:

Basically we have generic columns representing key/value pair.

### id |  k1  |  v1 |   k2     |   v2  |   k3 |   v3 | ....

1  | name | sam | last_name| smith | NULL | NULL | ...

In my application, I have many tables that have only one row and I would like to merge them into a generic table that has X number of columns with each rows representing singular table rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, this table doesn't need to normalized, and very minimal read and write. I HAVE to store in DB for very specific reason. Also another thing is that; since this table is acting like a properties file, I have to change my schema on regular tables anytime I want to add a property to my application that is being read from DB (not scalable...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Entity-Attribute-Value.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)  Also called a "Name-Value Table" or an "Open Schema."

This is an [SQL Antipattern](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back).  It fails many rules of relational database design, and it's incredibly hard to maintain.  I recommend against it.

See more of my thoughts about EAV in my answer to the question "[Product table, many kinds of product, each product has many parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695752/#695860)"

Comment: Yep, in the long run, doing this will make you cry. For the first 5 minutes though it seems fantastic!!

Comment: Amen, Bill! +1 for the focus on long-run maintainability. Lots of tables really hardly ever is an issue - "magic" tables like this will be - for sure!

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea. Basically you should use your relational database as a relational database.

Key/value pairs ordinarily aren't the advised storage method but at least single rows with a single key and a single value are "correct".

If you put multiple pairs in one row, it raises a number of issues:

1. How do you find a particular key?
2. Can that key be in k1, k2 or k3? Or is it always in a specific column?
3. How do you enforce that?
4. How do you make it performant?

Model your entities as entities with known attributes. That's what databases are for.

Comment: Yes, at least, that's what *relational* databases are for.