# How would you design your database to allow user-defined schema

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, schema, entity-attribute-value

If you have to create an application like - let's say a blog application, creating the database schema is relatively simple. You have to create some tables, tblPosts, tblAttachments, tblCommets, tblBlaBla… and that's it (ok, i know, that's  a bit simplified but you understand what i mean).

What if you have an application where you want to allow users to define parts of the schema **at runtime**. Let's say you want to build an application where users can log any kind of data. One user wants to log his working hours (startTime, endTime, project Id, description), the next wants to collect cooking recipes, others maybe stock quotes, the weekly weight of their babies, monthly expenses they spent for food, the results of their favorite football teams or whatever stuff you can think about.

How would you design a database to hold all that very very different kind of data? Would you create a generic schema that can hold all kind of data, would you create new tables reflecting the user data schema or do you have another great idea to do that?

If it's important: I have to use SQL Server / Entity Framework

Answer (score 10):

There's no way you can predict how complex their data requirements will be.  Entity-Attribute-Value is one typical solution many programmers use, but it might be be sufficient, for instance if the user's data would conventionally be modeled with multiple tables.

I'd serialize the user's custom data as XML or YAML or JSON or similar semi-structured format, and save it in a text BLOB.

You can even create *inverted indexes* so you can look up specific values among the attributes in your BLOB.  See http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql (the technique works in any RDBMS, not just MySQL).

Also consider using a document store such as [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org).  These technologies do not need to conform to relational database conventions.  You can add new attributes to any document at runtime, without needing to redefine the schema.  But it's a tradeoff -- having no schema means your app can't depend on documents/rows being similar throughout the collection.

---

I'm a critic of the Entity-Attribute-Value anti-pattern.

I've written about EAV problems in my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Here's an SO answer where I list some problems with Entity-Attribute-Value:  "[Product table, many kinds of products, each product has many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695752/#695860)."

Here's a blog I posted the other day with some more discussion of EAV problems:  "[EAV FAIL](https://karwin.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/21/eav-fail/)."

And be sure to read this blog "[Bad CaRMa](http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/)" about how attempting to make a fully flexible database nearly destroyed a company.

Comment: Care to elaborate on your criticisms of EAV Bill? I think it has its place, although there are constraints of course, but see the link in my response.

Comment: a blob for everything? yuck! that'll make even simple reporting damn near impossible, plus it'll be harder to get good performance.

Comment: @Booji Boy:  I agree, picking apart XML (or whatever) is hard in SQL, but the OP didn't say he needed to do any reporting.  It's just as likely that the whole blob would have to be loaded into the application to do whatever the user wanted to do with it.  And that's hard to anticipate anyway.

Comment: @Bill, I agree there's no perfect solution.  There's some interesting cross over with auditing too.  One point I'd like to make though, the 'Value' part (column or separate table) doesn't just have to consist of a single column, each data type can exist as a separate column, and it's the responsibility of the 'Attribute' to determine which column (data type) to use.

Comment: @Si: Right, I've seen that solution too.  It solves the problem of data-type validation, but none of the other problems of EAV.  Plus  it makes queries even more unintelligible.

Comment: @Bill re your blog post - Bad CaRMa - while it might have been a flop at "Upstart", quite a few companies (Siebel, SAP, Oracle to name a few big shrink wrapped software solutions) have implemented this kind of an extensible model quite successfully.

Comment: Although - to be fair - all these projects were executed by large Software companies with large pools of developers who  had either built database systems or had worked extensively using database systems.

Comment: @quixver, right, it takes a lot of work to make EAV do what normal SQL does quite easily.

Answer (score 5):

I would go for a Hybrid Entity-Attribute-Value model, so like Antony's reply, you have EAV tables, but you also have default columns (and class properties) which will always exist.

Here's a [great article](http://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/articlerender.fcgi?artid=2110957) on what you're in for :)

As an additional comment, I knocked up a prototype for this approach using Linq2Sql in a few days, and it was a workable solution. Given that you've mentioned Entity Framework, I'd take a look at version 4 and their [POCO support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853(VS.100).aspx), since this would be a good way to inject a hybrid EAV model without polluting your EF schema.

Comment: That's a great article you found Si - bookmarked for next time!

Answer (score 3):

On the surface, a schema-less or document-oriented database such as [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) for the custom user data sounds ideal. But I guess that doesn't help much if you can't use anything but SQL and EF.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the Entity Framework, but I would lean towards the Entity-Attribute-Value (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-Attribute-Value_model) database model.

So, rather than creating tables and columns on the fly, your app would create attributes (or collections of attributes) and then your end users would complete the values.

But, as I said, I don't know what the Entity Framework is supposed to do for you, and it may not let you take this approach.

Comment: FWIW, Entity Framework is a nascent ORM library for the Microsoft .NET framework.

Comment: Thanks for that Bill - I'm not a .NET guy so had never heard of it. I'm thinking, though, that an ORM would struggle with EAV?

Comment: It's possible with ORM (in fact easier!), you can have a business object interface which is composed of some EAV interface property. e.g. IEntity composed of List<IAttribute> where IAttribute is composed of List<IValue> (and also links back to IEntity). So long as your defining your entity -> attribute -> values in the standard way your ORM tool does, it's just like any other relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Not as a critical comment, but it may help save some of your time to point out that this is one of those Don Quixote Holy Grail type issues. There's an eternal quest for probably over 50 years to make a user-friendly database design interface.

The only quasi-successful ones that have gained any significant traction that I can think of are 1. Excel (and its predecessors), 2. Filemaker (the original, not its current flavor), and 3. (possibly, but doubtfully) Access. Note that the first two are limited to basically one table.

I'd be surprised if our collective conventional wisdom is going to help you break the barrier. But it would be wonderful.

Comment: Second this you can either be very limited and totally non performant with some entity attribute scheme, or, you can come up with something flexiable, complex and a nightmare to maintain which is really just a piss poor implementation of data defnition language.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than re-implement sqlservers "CREATE TABLE" statement, which was done many years ago by a team of programmers who were probably better than you or I, why not work on exposing SQLSERVER in a limited way to the users -- let them create thier own schema in a limited way and leverage the power of SQLServer to do it properly.

Comment: This is actually a great comment. But as this is an entity-framework question, it would require updating your entities to incorporate these fields. So then you might aswell just add them. Secondarily, it's worth noting that users changing your SQL schema could have serious performance implications (execution plans that need to be recalculated etc)

Answer (score 0):

I would just give them a copy of SQL Server Management Studio, and say, "go nuts!" Why reinvent a wheel within a wheel?

Comment: Not a good idea since the user has no idea what "SQL" or a "Management Studio" is. Funny answer but not really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/04/04/edmgen2-now-with-reverse-engineering-options.aspx) you can do it but it's a lot of hard work :) If performance is not a concern an xml solution could work too though that is also alot of work.

Comment: I know that article but i have no clue why that should be an answer to my question!?

Comment: Fair enough, was a quick answer. You could of course leave the "dynamic" parts of the schema to some other engine that is the beauty of domain driven design anyways but I have a hard time figuring out how you would solve that with EF or L2S. I mean what type of application would that be targeting logging everyones various needs anyway? Is it just for the fun of it or is it a real project?