# User Defined Fields Structure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

I am currently building a system which will need to implement user defined fields.

I currently have the following EAV 'like' structure.  The 'Person' table acts as a master table.

**Person Table**

```
PersonID(PK)
PersonName
```

**DataField Table**

```
FieldID(PK)
FieldName
FieldType
```

**DataFieldValue Table**

```
ID(PK)
DataFieldID(FK)
PersonID(FK)
StringValue
IntValue
LongValue
DateValue
DateAdded
DateUpdated
```

I have managed to use this structure successfully in a prototype.  However my production system which will have to cater for significantly higher number of records.  My preference would be to stick with this approach but the 'DataFieldValue' table is likely to get quite large.

Will this be safe in my production system or would it be better to break this down somehow?

I am using SQL Server and ASP.net MVC 4 (with EF 5).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you design your database to allow user-defined schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923778/how-would-you-design-your-database-to-allow-user-defined-schema)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to queries (SELECT) on data field values i would take a much radical approach, and add some no sql + JSON goodness.

This is how data in my Person table would look

```
ID PersonName ExtraProperties
----------
1  ABC        [{'FieldId':1,'FieldName':'Age', 'Value':22},{'FieldId':2,'FieldName':'Gender', 'Value':'Male'}]
```

Using libraries like [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) you can serialize and deserialize this content and use it within your code.

You loose things like adhoc query on the data (which is difficult even with this schema), consistent (fieldid may mismatch) but you gain on performance and ease of use.

I also suggest you to look at dynamics in C# and see if it can help.

Comment: Thanks chandermani, but unfortunately I do need to run SELECT queries on the data.