# Database design - alternatives for Entity Attribute Value (EAV)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

see [How to design a product table for many kinds of product where each product has many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695752/product-table-many-kinds-of-product-each-product-has-many-parameters) for similar topic.

My question: i want to design a database, that will be used for a production facility of different types of products where each product has its own (number of) parameters.
because i want the serial numbers to be in one tabel for overview purposes i have a problem with these different paraeters .

One solution could be EAV, but it has its downsides, certainly because we have +- 5 products with  every product +- 20.000 serial numbers (records). it looks a bit overkill to me...

I just don't know how one could design a database so that you have an attribute in a mastertable that says: 'hey, you could find details of this record in THAT detail-table".
'in a way that you qould easely query the results)

currenty i am using Visual Basic & Acces 2007. but i'm going to Visual Basic & MySQL.

thanks for your help.

Bob

Comment: In what way does the original question you linked to not answer your problem? It seems like you are facing the same issues as the original post.

Comment: Because there isn't a detailed instruction on, what they called Class Table Inheritance.

i don't know how to make a query with an JOIN where the Joined table name is not know at query design time (= because it is a parameter from the first table where you make a join with)

Comment: With Class Table Inheritance you map each of your products to their own table and you have to know which table to query when you want to get at the data. I don't think the Class Table Inheritance design has a "type" encoded in the data. For that you would have to use dynamic SQL which would have speed issues.

Comment: You said "One solution could be EAV, but it has its downsides.." what are the downsides specific to your situation? Personally I haven't dealt with EAV soluitions that often, but with 20k serial numbers per product I'm finding it hard to see you modelling it any other way i.e. would you want a table with 20k columns, even if it's possible! :)

Comment: Hi Tony
thanks for your replies !
what i meant with 20k serial numbers was that i have approx. 20000 products per producttype.

i agree that one solution could be 'knowing wich table to query'. but i am not a expert in these things, but i am not sure this is the way it is 'supposed to be' done.

Comment: How different are the attributes you want to store of one product to the next? I assume (as you are asking a question on SO) it's not possible to have a [ProductGroup] table linking to a [Products] table with the 20k rows in it?

Comment: Try Streams Platform https://github.com/anomalylabs/streams-platform . It proposes an alternative way with meta-programming and a bit of DDD patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this:

```
product [productid, title, price, datecreated, datemodified, etc]
attribute [attributeid, title]
productattribute [productid, attributeid, value, unit]
```

Example:

```
[product]
productid  title    price   datecreated  datemodified
1          LCD TV   99.95   2010-01-01   2010-01-01
2          Car      12356   2010-01-01   2010-01-02
3          B/W TV   12.95   1960-01-01   1960-01-01

[attribute]
attributeid  title
10           Colors
11           Dimensions
12           Passengers

[productattribute]
productid  attributeid  value  unit
1          10           16     million
1          11           32     inch
2          12           4      adults
3          10           2      colors
3          11           6      inch
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you probably need to learn more about the available design patterns when dealing with this sort of problem as there isn't a one-size-fits-all solution.

I recommend picking up a copy of [Patterns of Enterprise Application Delvelopment](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa) to help you on your way. Sorry that I'm not able to answer your question directly (hopefully someone else here on SO can) but I think the answer given in the question you linked to is about as good as it gets.