# Optional structure sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, entity-relationship, relational-database

DB world is not mine, so perhaps the question is trivial

Imagine designing a DB that store data from different kinds of items (like datatypes)

I have no idea how I should do it, but this is how I'm making it

```
id | quantity | price ... Kind | ID_k_foreing |
```

then for every kind of items would be a table with properties of each type

so via software I could compare the kind and then make the joins to the appropriate table

like this pseudocode

```
switch(kind)
{
case chess_game:
      the join is made with a table like this:
      id_k| material | length | weigth ..
case car_toy:
      the join is made with a table like this:
      id_k| color | velocity | remote_control ...
case doll:
      the join is made with a table like this:
      id_k| name | height | clothes ..

...

}
```

There is some standar way to solve this "data type" problem in structure 
without adding tricky software functions?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695752/119477).

Bill Karwin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695752/product-table-many-kinds-of-product-each-product-has-many-parameters/695860#695860) breaks it down this way.

> You have at least these five options
>   for modeling the type hierarchy you
>   describe:
>
> [Single Table](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) Inheritance: one table
>   for all Product types, with enough
>   columns to store all attributes of all
>   types. This means a lot of columns,
>   most of which are NULL on any given
>   row.
>
> [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html): one table for
>   Products, storing attributes common to
>   all product types. Then one table per
>   product type, storing attributes
>   specific to that product type.
>
> [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html): no table
>   for common Products attributes.
>   Instead, one table per product type,
>   storing both common product
>   attributes, and product-specific
>   attributes.
>
> [Serialized LOB](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serializedLOB.html): One table for
>   Products, storing attributes common to
>   all product types. One extra column
>   stores a BLOB of semi-structured data,
>   in XML, YAML, JSON, or some other
>   format. This BLOB allows you to store
>   the attributes specific to each
>   product type. You can use fancy Design
>   Patterns to describe this, such as
>   Facade and Memento. But regardless you
>   have a blob of attributes that can't
>   be easily queried within SQL; you have
>   to fetch the whole blob back to the
>   application and sort it out there.
>
> [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-Attribute-Value_model): One table for
>   Products, and one table that pivots
>   attributes to rows, instead of
>   columns. EAV is not a valid design
>   with respect to the relational
>   paradigm, but many people use it
>   anyway. This is the "Properties
>   Pattern" mentioned by another answer.
>   See other questions with the eav tag
>   on StackOverflow for some of the
>   pitfalls.

You'll have to sort out which one works for you.