# MySQL database structure to store objects of different types with different properties

Tags: mysql, types, entity-attribute-value

I would like to create MySQL database structure to incorporate the following case:

I need to store groups of objects of different types with different properties (name, number and size) in the same data table, avoiding the use of EAV data model. This database model must me easy to extend, search, index...

Example of objects:

- cars (maker, name, year, color, weight, height, engine type...)
- TV sets (maker, name, type, diagonal...)
- pets (breed, age, color...)
  ...

Is this possible?

Comment: SQL is designed for fixed records (tuples). These represent non-fixed records. EAV is one way to transpose a non-fixed set of "attributes" onto fixed records. Of course (and in some systems they are), tables are created/updated on per-need basis with the appropriate record structure.

Comment: @pst, perhaps you should turn your comment into an answer. I wouldn't know what to add to that, and I'd like to see this question off the “unanswered” queue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Product table, many kinds of product, each product has many parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695752/product-table-many-kinds-of-product-each-product-has-many-parameters)