# Storing dynamic properties of objects in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, schema

I am trying to store "dynamic" properties about objects in SQL. As an example, let's say I have a table called `objs` that has two columns (`id`, `name`). Now some users may want to store a property called `hocus` while others may want to store a property called `pocus` (or even `banana`). Anything really.

My thought is to create two tables, `props` and `obj_props`. `props` would have two columns (`id` and `prop_name`), and `obj_props` would have (`obj_id`, `prop_id`, and `value`).

My only concern is this seems like a lot of overhead if there are millions of objects, each with 20-30 properties. I know I could create an index in `obj_props` on `obj_id` and `prop_id` but will this still be able to perform well? Is there a better solution for something like this? I'm looking into MongoDB but the lack of joins is frustrating.

Comment: I'd recommend to search nosql db that fits well to your application reqiremnts. The method you've described is a variant of common EAV antipattern. It can be used for small amount of dynamic data, but it performs really bad when you have millions of objects.

Comment: Have you looked at hstore?

Comment: Indeed we've been using hstore for some years now, it works very well. We're using some JSON also, since pg9.3.

Comment: I hadn't heard of hstore before but after doing some research, that looks like the ultimate way to go, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been discussed repeatedly before:

- [This DBA.stackexchange.com post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27057/model-with-variable-number-of-properties-of-different-types)
- [Dynamic table columns based on user preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17014952/398670)
- [Should I place EAV values in a datatype table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17649598/398670)
- [How to represent many similar attributes of an entity in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13425574/398670)
- [Database design - should I use 30 columns or 1 column with all data in form of JSON/XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13294003/398670)
- [What is the maximum number of columns in a PostgreSQL select query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12606842/398670)

The short version: EAV has its place, but it's often better to use `json`, XML, or `hstore`. PostgreSQL 9.4's enhanced `json` will probably become the most attractive choice, as it combines the advantages of `json` and `hstore`.

Comment: Yes I completely agree with you, JSON in 9.4 looks like the silver bullet. For now though, hstore will work for most of my use cases as I don't need nesting of the data. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4):

First, you should start with a proper database schema (using standard [data model patterns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example)) so you can avoid this as much as possible.

Martin Fowler recommends using either a serialized LOB (such as JSON or XML), or allowing the user to edit their own database schema (which is my preferred method):

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UserDefinedField.html

Bill Karwin has a link in the comments on creating a second table to index values in the blob field

Comment: See my presentation [Extensible Data Modeling with MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling).