# Database design best practice: Storing string and numbers in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Building a data driven web based application. Stated simply, how the front end is structured is defined by metadata stored as part of the database. One design consideration comes up frequently: how to store values that can take on different data types. For example, the input required from users are defined in a `measurement` table. The default measurement value can be string, int, or double depending on the measurement definition.

I have three possible solutions:
Option 1: Store all default values as `varchar` and `cast` to the correct type on the fly.

Option 2: Create table columns for each data type, and store null values in the columns that does not apply.

Option 3: Create separate tables to store values for each data type.

What would be the correct and professional way to handle this.

[image: designoptions]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I handle different data types in an Entity-Attribute-Value design (e.g. single table with multiple columns or multiple tables per data type)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105644/how-can-i-handle-different-data-types-in-an-entity-attribute-value-design-e-g)

Comment: There is a [good article on sqlteam.com](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/articles/12117.aspx) about the main approaches to this problem. There are also about [a million articles on the web](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eav+vs+relational+model+sql) about EAV vs Relational Model.

Comment: I'm struggling so this is for interest only ... what measurement value would be a string?

Comment: @CHill60 - I'm with you, anything I measure is likely going to end up a double, no matter what.  I guess it could end up 'integer' if I'm supposed to round it off... except for a good portion of it's range, a double can precisely represent an integer.

Comment: Thanks all, definitly an duplicate of the EAV design question. I did not however know the generic term for the design pattern and therefore my internet searches did not bring up relevent results.

Comment: @CHill60 The term attribute would be more appropriate to a string "measurements". Again, I was not able to identify the design pattern when I asked the question. There are lots of information available with regard to the entity-attribute-value scenario and the use thereof.