# Lightweight method for adding persistent data to ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, persistence

Aside from creating SQL SERVER tables, is there a light-weight technology or method for adding persistent data to an ASP.NET website which works with LINQ and preferably doesn't require much in terms installing installation/packages to a project nor learning large frameworks?

Session state is one option but only if it is run out of process and configured for SQL Server which doesn't fit my needs.

Comment: I'm not sure it fits your specifications, but http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: or http://www.mongodb.com/

Comment: @JCG MonogoDB sounds like exactly what I need. But, I'm wondering if just writing an XML file might work in my case.

Comment: You can use LINQ to query XML data.  I'd investigate that route before using something in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options to satisfy the question:

1.
Session State -> Only if configured for out-of-process and SQL Server.

2.
NoSql Database Solutions -> MonogoDb, RavenDB, Sqlite.org

3.
SQL Server Key/Value Singleton -> Create a table and store key/value pairs as a single entry in the table or create a generic key/value table. Keys will need to be unique and values will need to scalars only or multiple values crammed into one key using a deliminator. A generic key/value table will need to store all keys as strings and rely on type conversion either implicit to the program or stored as an extra column.

See below

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

[How to design a product table for many kinds of product where each product has many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695752/product-table-many-kinds-of-product-each-product-has-many-parameters#695860)

4.
Create an XML file or other flat file and store/write key/values to it. May require special permissions.

I will likely go with option #3 because it satisfies my current requirements best but will explore the NoSQL solutions for future projects.