# Stuck in database structure with many kind of tables

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I'm creating a structure of DB by E/R Diagram, but I'm stuck since some days on this problem. Probably I'm wrong in the way I'm doing it, so if you think I can do it in a better way, would be lovely :)

The scenario is:
I have N users who owns N sensors, not all the sensors (in the future could increase to 300 kinds of sensors) have the same features(columns), so I suppose I need a table for each sensor and then list the inside the values collected.

[image: structure]

I have some doubts regarding how to referentiate the tabless for "kind sensor"-"Sensors" wich columns should I put on the "sensor" table, also in this way I will get many tables. Do yo have any hint?

Comment: I think that you should list all features as columns in one table and the sensor that does not have a specific feature , the cell for this feature should be set to null .

Comment: @DrewPierce a user can have from 1 to N sensors. If I use columns, i could probably get 300 columns, where for each row it's just one or two cells who are not nulled. Is it good to it?

And the tables here are just a sketch, so i'm very openminded to start over again :)

Comment: @DrewPierce It's the opposite. 2 or 3 columns filled for each row only. Meaning almost 297 nulls for each row.

Btw In near term I might have 50 types, but in long term could scale to 300.

Comment: You are trying to implement inheritance in a relational model. [Here are the most common approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/q/695752/1446005). (your question is a duplicate but you have my +1 for a very well formed question, thank you).

Comment: @RandomSeed you gave me the best and most complete answer with your link, why don't you answer with this comment, so I can mark you as best answer? Thanks!

Comment: My marking the question as duplicate is my answer :) Do upvote answers in the other topic if you found it useful.

Comment: i faced a very similar issue without writing my case i was wondering if there is any chance the table name of kind sensor and an the primary key of the particular row. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest and easiest way to do it is to make all specific columns in your table "sensors" and have one foreign key to another table "sensor_type" which is consisted of 2 columns

```
table "sensor_type"
id_type  - identifier (primary key)
description - description of your sensor (heat, temperature sensor ... )
```

Your table sensor then looks like

```
table "sensor"
id_sensor                       identifier (primary key)
id_type                         foreign key references sensor_type table
size                            default null, if type 2 or 3 then something
weight                          default null, if type 1 and 3 then something
etc...
```

You need to understand this is probably one of many solutions which can solve your problem. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

May be it's better to introduce Many to many relationship between sensors and features they have? For example like this:

```
Sensors
 sensor_id (pk)
 type

Features
 feature_id (pk)
 name

SensorsFeatures (Ownership table)
 sensor_id (foreign key to Sensors.sensor_id)
 feature_id (foreign key to Features.feature_id)
```

If you need to store values of these features (weight, height, width,...) , you can do it in SensorsFeatures table.

Comment: Actually what I ment by features, was the different kind of data collected. :(

Comment: Give please example of any of these features

Comment: If I've got you right, you also need to store values of these features, if so, you can do it in SensorsFeatures table in some field, e.g. "value".

Answer (score 0):

You should add new table e.g. sensor_type for all sensors, where each row will be the sensor with uniq id which can be added to user.

The idea is to separate sensors with type or something else which is the most common thing beaten sensors.