# how to make sure that product specs is for the category entity?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, entity-relationship, rdbms

I have the following table:

1. products (id, name, price, category_id)
2. categories (id, name, description)

now because each category's products may have different attributes than other category's product I want to use [EVA](https://inviqa.com/blog/eav-data-model) but here is my problem:

I want to make sure that any product attribute's value is being added belong to the category of that product and not allowing the addition of arrtibutes that does not belong to it.

would you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: If you have different attributes expected for different products, then perhaps you want a separate table for each product.  Unfortunately, MySQL does not enforce `check` constraints.

Comment: I assume the suggestion above is a joke. Have a separate table which identifies which attributes can belong to which product.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make sure that any product attribute's value is being added belong to the category of that product and not allowing the addition of attributes that does not belong to it.  would you please tell me how to do this?

Sure.  It is a fairly common requirement, and quite straight-forward, at both the modelling and SQL levels. However, due to the promotion of primitive 1960's Record Filing Systems as "relational" by the "theoreticians", and the suppression of Relational methods by the same crowd, it is unknown.

Whereas the RFS is physical (`Record IDs` linking records, not rows), the *Relational Model* is **Logical**, using logical keys, which link rows not records.  And Relational Keys provide **meaning**.  So first the concept needs to be understood, and then the implementation is easy.

### 1960's Record Filing System

Your files:

[image: RFS]

- All my data models are rendered in [IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/), the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My [IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf) is essential reading for beginners.
- The [IDEF1X Anatomy](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Model%20Anatomy.pdf) is a refresher for those who have lapsed

### Relational Database • Concept • Subtype

This is the concept that you need to understand.

[image: Concept]

- As per your requirement, each Category requires different attributes in Product, and each is mutually exclusive from the others.
- It is an ordinary Subtype cluster, Exclusive in this case.
- Some might call it "metadata", as in, it is beyond the data, and it has a defining effect on Product.
- More info on [Subtypes](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf).

### 1960's Record Filing System • Implementation

Now for the implementation, using the given files.

[image: Requirement]

- Maintain Category as a logical Key (`CHAR` Key, replete with meaning, not a `Record Id`).
- We deploy the Exclusive Subtype cluster in Product, with the Category as the Discriminator.
- However, due to the use of `Record IDs`, which are physical, and which are not logical keys, but implemented as `PRIMARY KEY`, which will confuse the hell out of anyone, the rows in the Product file can be duplicated

  - each logical Product row needs to be unique
  - which means, according to Dr E F Codd's *Relational Model*, using a Key that is "made up from the data"
  - Product `Name` is the only possibility for a PK

### Relational Database • Implementation

If we elevate the system to Relational, and prevent the duplication of rows (as opposed to records), which is prohibited:

[image: Implementation]

- Human users will not use numbers for Identifiers.  The `ProductId` is not seen or used by them.
- The `Name` is the only unique row (Product) Identifier, however it is too long to be nominated Primary Key.  Nevertheless it must be Unique.
- Users will use a short code as a Product Identifier.
- Which makes the `ProductId` quite useless and redundant (one **additional** column and one **additional** index).
- As usual, this is also the fewest columns and indices.

### SQL

All the above is ordinary SQL, the data sublanguage for the *Relational Model*.  It can be implemented with full protection and integrity using ordinary SQL `CONSTRAINTs`, etc.  The [Subtype document](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf) provides full implementation details.

- However, note that MySQL and PusGreSQL are **not SQL** (they do not comply with the SQL requirement, and are absent many of the ordinary functions of SQL), and thus their use of the term `SQL` is fraudulent.
- Further, they have no Server Architecture, which means performance is horrendous, and concurrency is pathetic.