# Mapping Relationships With Several Tables Relating to a Single Table in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

I have a table that contains user permissions for various objects/entities that looks like:

```
object_type //an enum referring the the type of object that this record applies to
object_id //the id of the object
user_id
can_edit
etc.
```

This would be related to several other tables in my project that don't really have anything in common (photos would be one example).  To get the permissions for an object I would like to be able to do something like:

```
//get the first photo along with all of the user permissions related to it
context.Set<Photos>()
     .Include(p=>p.UserPermissions)
     .FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id == 1)
```

I can restructure the database if need be, so I'd like to here what you think the best solution for this is.

Comment: It would be about 100x smarter to use a database that supports Row Security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that they do all have something in common.  They are all resources that can be controlled regarding permissions.  In this context, "resources" is a generalization of "photos", etc. Or, expressed in terms of object classes, photo is a subclass of resource.

In that context, I'm going to suggest that your question may have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695752/how-to-design-a-product-table-for-many-kinds-of-product-where-each-product-has-m/695860#695860).  This is an answer by Bill Karwin that describes several ways to design for an inheritance type situation.  It's earned a lot of votes.