# Use subgroups in databases

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship

I'm currently looking for the best way to use subgroups within databases.

As you can see on the picture the "Block" object can either be a "Calendar", "Survey" or "Gallery" object. Each of the object has a different structure.

[image]
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UfYK.png)

What would be the best approach to use following structure in a database like MySQL or Cassandra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options:

- [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html): one table for all Product types, with enough columns to store all attributes of all types. This means a lot of columns, most of which are NULL on any given row.
- [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html): one table for Products, storing attributes common to all product types. Then one table per product type, storing attributes specific to that product type.
- [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html): no table for common Products attributes. Instead, one table per product type, storing both common product attributes, and product-specific attributes.

These are copied from one of my old answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/695860/20860

As always, the "best" solution depends on how you will query the data.