# What is a good database design for linking multiple tables

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to link multiple tables as shown in the design below. There is a **Classes** table that has types that are tables on their own and **different** from each other. A user can register a class type of either **Class A**, **Class B**, **Class C**, etc.

Is there a better way to approach this other than the design I have below?

[image]

Comment: Answers to this question also give you a good idea what other design patters are available to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695752/how-to-design-a-product-table-for-many-kinds-of-product-where-each-product-has-m

Comment: @Shadow Yes, it does. Thanks