# RDBMS Entity with many predefined attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, postgresql

I have following abstracted model in my application.

```
Entity "Product"
Id | Name | Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | ... | Attribute N = 50
```

Attributes are fixed by a business model and can only have specific, predefined characteristics, i.e.:

```
Attribute 1
1 | Blue
2 | Red
3 | Yellow

Attribute 2 
1 | S
2 | M
3 | L
```

Referencing these attributes by a one-to-many or many-to-many would make sense, if I would only have a hand full of so defined attributes... However, we have a lot of these attributes, lets say N=50 predefined, specific attributes.

That would mean a query must perform N=50 joins to receive the entire product from database. That does not seem like a well-performing, well-scaling approach, especially when increasing the amount of products (several tens of thousands).

In a NoSQL database like MongoDB I would design it probably like as including the references directly in the same document:

```
{
    "Id":"1"
    "name":"somename"
    "attributes": {
        "attribute1":{"1":"red"}
        "attribute2":{"1":"S"}
        ...
        "attribute50":{"1":"something"}
    }
}
```

But for SQL and RDBMS im kind of stuck or can't find a proper solution.

Comment: 50 columns? I do not see a problem...

Comment: @Akina Thanks for commenting. That would lead to 50 joins per query, when asking for the entire product. Isn't that too many joins to be handled efficiently and quickly?

Comment: *That would lead to 50 joins per query* ?? Do you mean that these 50 columns are not values but foreign keys? If so then think about EAV pattern or single JSON column. Or maybe you need in Faceted Search?

Comment: Yes, it would be foreign keys, like fk=1 for Attribute 1 = Blue. Another approach would be, instead of putting in the foreign key, putting in the actual value? In this case a string. Or should I defined a custom data type in database?

Comment: If the lists are relatively stable, then you could use enums instead of lookup tables.

Comment: Alternatively, look into one of the dynamic properties design patterns as Akina has already suggested, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695752/how-to-design-a-product-table-for-many-kinds-of-product-where-each-product-has-m